# Uploading a file in asp.net in one of the folders listed in the solution explorer

Tags: asp.net, file, upload, solution-explorer

I am trying to upload a file to my Asp.net website. The issue is that I want the file to be saved on the web server itself in one of the folders that I included in the solution of the website while developing it in visual studio. 
I am not able to get access rights to that folder and I wonder how the user will have access to that folder. I want to save the file in the folder and allow other users to download it.

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/folder"));
```

The error I get is:

```
Access to the path 'C:_________________________________is denied
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank You

Shaleen

Comment: Problem with yr permissions. Have to grant read/write.

Answer (score 0):

You should grant read and write permissions to the ASPNET / **NETWORK SERVICE** user for the specified folder. If for some reason you stuck on this, you can just for test set write permissions to the everyone user to verify that the problem is resolved. After that remove the permissions and test again with the NETWORK SERVICE account.

Check this MSDN article for more information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx.

Comment: Write permission to every user??

Comment: No doubt that this is not recommended. As I wrote you could test by giving permissions to everyone just for test, if the solution for the ASPNET / NETWORK SERVICE user doesn't work.

Comment: There is a very detailed article about the NETWORK SERVICE account in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx. Scroll down to look at the Granting File Access to Network Service section.